# Gui Tools to get more info on Programs / Apps

Tags: 20.04, gnome, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension, gnome-panel

I've used Ubuntu (20.04 atm), and looking for something to make it a bit more user friendly, given apt, snap, appimages, etc. that mean programs can be stored in all sorts of locations.

While I like to keep many things in the commandline, it's often the case that the stuff in commandline is hard to come by. Names for applications might be harder to remember, the locations of those programs aren't findable if not added to path, etc.

So, sometimes I have a program I know was installed a while ago, such as [syncthing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8zrM.png), which I can find in the Ubuntu global search. Are there any tools, for Gnome, Ubuntu, or otherwise, that might help me to get more information on this program (e.g. launcher location, application location, etc.)? Keeping in mind, I may not know the terminal-based name for this program (in many cases).

Comment: I use synaptic to find programs and it has helped me learn actual names. `sudo apt install synaptic`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The venerable Synaptic Package manager, not installed by default (since a long time) may help here. Its "search" function allows you to search package names *and* descriptions. Once you located a package, right-click properties provides a wealth of information, including which files were installed by the package.

[image]

Install Synaptic Package manager from the software store, or using the terminal with the command `sudo apt install synaptic`.